# Initializing a malloc'ed string index to NULL

Tags: c, arrays, null, malloc

For example, say I just created a char **strings by using malloc.

How would I set each index strings[i] to NULL? Is it initially set to NULL? Because when I check with another function for an index equal to NULL, like
    if(strings[i] == NULL);
It never seems to work.
Any help?
Sorry I'm new to dynamic memory..

Comment: `malloc` does not initialize the memory it allocations. `calloc` provides memory set to 0. (`man calloc`)

Comment: @rici sorry I made a mistake with my original post. I have char **strings. So how would I be able to set strings[i] to point to NULL is what I'm asking.

Comment: @E46: If you're using a standard platform, the answer is the same because 0 is 0. However, if you really wanted to be pedantically standard-compliant, you'd initialize each element to 0 manually with a loop, because it is theoretically possible that (char*)0 is not 0. You probably want to ignore this comment until much later in your learning project.

Answer (score 1):

NULL is usually defined as a macro that expands to (void *)0

You can use `calloc` to allocate and initialize to zero. Be sure to use the correct number of parentheses.

```
char* buffer = calloc(4, sizeof(char));

if(*buffer == 0) {
    printf("%s\n", "*buffer == 0");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`malloc()` only allocates memory. You should use `calloc()` which allocates memory and zeroes the allocated memory.

Being an array of pointers, each element will now be equal to `NULL`.

```
char **strings = calloc(1024, sizeof *string);
if(strings[1] == NULL)
    printf("%s", "yes. NULL");
```